# Android Room using Update but not set All Column in entity

Tags: android, android-room

Is Room Ignore data that are null in Entity Send for Update table ?!
I want to Update part of Column in entity but I wounder Store new data in entity class and send it to Update in DAO is replace other data in that row or not ?!

for Example if Entity Class is:

```
@Entity(tableName = "ITEM_TABLE")
public class Item
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @NotNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ID")
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "COLUMN_TITLE")
    public String title;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "COLUMN_WEIGHT")
    public String weight;
}
```

and Request for Update like This:

```
Item item = new Item();
item.title = "new Title";
item.id = 2;
ItemDAO.update(item);
```

if entity with id = 2 exist and it's weight = "250" what happened if I update it this way ?!

Comment: The weight here will become null. If you need to perform some sort of Update that limits only to some column then use `@Query`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define your own DAO.

```
@Dao
public interface IDaoAccessStuff {

    @Query("UPDATE SET COLUMN_TITLE=:text WHERE id=:id")
    void UpdateColumnById (String text, int id);
    ...
    @Insert
    void insertStuff (Stuffstuff);

    @Update
    void updateExercise (Exercises exercise);
}
```

Then:

```
@Database (entities = {Stuff.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AStuffDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract IDaoStuffExercise daoAccess();
}
```

Finally:

```
private AStuffDatabase aStuffDatabase;
...
RoomDatabase.Builder<AExerciseDatabase> builder;
builder = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
           AStuffDatabase.class,
            YOUR_DATABASE_NAME);
aStuffDatabase = builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
... 
aStuffDatabase.daoAccess().updateStuff(yourString, theId);
```

Also, unless you specify that the column should not accept null values, as shown below:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "COLUMN_TITLE")
@NonNull 
private String title;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but the problem is not Null value. problem is Room is Replace all Item's value each time We Call Update. I Just want to Update one Column data.

Comment: @mohmadaliYaghmay, I updated my answer. Take a look and try it out.